# When Deserializing Json Object expected result is not correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview

While doing JSON example, I have reached a point where i have a gridview and it should be bind to datasource. The datasource is in Json object

The code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                var list = employee.CreateEmployees();

                var query = from emp in list.AsEnumerable()
                            select new
                            {
                                id = (int)emp.EmployeeId,
                                name = (string)emp.Name,
                                nic = (string)emp.Nic,
                                salary = (int)emp.Salary
                            };

                JObject o = JObject.FromObject(new
                {
                    Employees = query
                });

                Response.Write(o);
                Session["JsonEmployee"] = o;
            }
            LoadGrid();
        }
```

For loading Grid:

```
 void LoadGrid() {

           List<Employee> lst = new List<Employee>();
            var objects = (JObject)Session["JsonEmployee"];

            foreach (var v in objects)
            {
                lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(v.Value.ToString());

            }
            GridView1.DataSource = lst;
            GridView1.DataBind();


        }
```

All works fine but the only problem is that the EmployeeId is 0 for every employee.

Employee class is as:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string  Nic { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
..... 
}
```

**Note** in the json object every employee has correct id but when it convert it to list getting employeeid 0 for every employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the one object it's called id and in the other EmployeeId. Name them the same, it should solve the issue

Comment: Thanks very helpful!! one thing to ask we need to create the exactly same prop which we defined in our classes like i use Employeeid in class and in linq calling id which cause the trouble